# where to look for a bug. document, app delegate or both?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, crash

following situation: i have a document based App. by default when i open the app it displays just the menu on top of the screen. then i hit file->new and it opens up a brand new document.xib interface. working fine on my main pc. but on my secodnary pc running 10.6.8 the app crashes as soon as i run it. (code is compiled with the proper target...)

this application is crashing BEFORE i even see the main menu at the top. could the cause of the crash still be inside the document's xib file? or will it most likely be in the code that is outside the document part? what i mean is: is the code checked completely at the application lounch or does it onyl cause a crash when it reaches the code that is causing it?

thanks

edit

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 ??? 000000000000000000 0 + 0
1 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100def22e -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] + 416
2 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100def01b -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 259
3 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100dee406 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 336
4 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100deca91 loadNib + 226
5 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100debfa1 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading)_loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 248
6 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100debdd9 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 326
7 com.apple.AppKit 0x0000000100de935b NSApplicationMain + 279
8 mad-sharky.com.Stockuploader 0x0000000100001194 0x100000000 + 4500
```

Comment: What did you see in crash logs? It seem your main screen controller is creating trouble for you on 10.6.8..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem. here it is:

[image]

now it works without any problems!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies not in the XIB file, but rather in one of the objects in said file that is being instantiated incorrectly.  Something about the object is causing it's `-initWithCoder:` method to fail.  It appears you're probably not calling through to super in said method, and are simply returning self, which is not allowed.

The other possibility is that you have a "ghost outlet".  Sometimes, when an IBOutlet is created and linked, then the piece of code that declares it is removed, IB doesn't de-link the outlet, and NSCoder tries to dearchive a nil outlet.

Comment: Hello! thanks for your reply. i am very noobish on this since it is my first app. could you please tell me what the best way is to search for the problem and fix it? also, what do you mean with "It appears you're probably not calling through to super in said method, and are simply returning self, which is not allowed. " thanks!

Comment: @Justme Have you defined -initWithCoder: anywhere?

Comment: Then check IB for outlets with little warning arrows next to them.  If all else fails, remove, then relink every outlet.

Comment: no luck.. i discovered that it stopped working since one beta version in the past.. so i made a copy of the project and startedremoving things till it works. will post back when i find whats wrong.

Comment: the problem is caused by `@interface Document : NSPersistentDocument <NSStreamDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate>{` the NSStreamDelegate causes the crash.. any idea why?